# Mac OS terminal clipboard and clipboard for other application clipboard

Tags: macos, terminal

I am a new Mac OS terminal user.
Initially I can copy any texts from Notes/Google Chrome and simply press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to copy the content and <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> paste it into my terminal.
After I was trying to be *SMART*.
I put down a line in my `.profile` file
alias `cpwd="pwd | pbcopy"` and reloaded my terminal.

Now I can't to do that any more. Now the terminal can only recognise something I copied within terminal i.e. any text that I <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>` inside terminal can only be <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> into terminal. Are there anyway for me to restore my initial setting, so that I can copy text from other application (Notes/chrome) and paste into terminal?

Comment: Thanks for helping me formatting my post.

Comment: I think I have fixed the problem. I think somehow I created a separate clipboard server which isolated my terminal clipboard from rest of the application. I reconfigured the my alias in my .profile file (didn't fix my problem) and downloaded [This file](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard), in theory this should only fix my pbcopy & phpaste in tmux session, however, somehow it fixed my problem, these two separate clipboard get unified.